# Why I can't center the components horizontally in the div?

Tags: html, css

I have block and inside the blocks, there are three boxes. The CSS is

```
.blocks {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;
  height: 350px; 
}


.box1, .box2, .box3 {

    width: 33.333%;
    height: 300px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;

}
```

In the box, there is an image and a text. I want them centered horizontally.
So I did as

```
.box1, .box2, .box3 {

    width: 33.333%;
    height: 300px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

But they are not centered. As shown in the image.
[image: img]
My HTML is

```
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box1" style="background-color:lavender;">
       <!-- One image and text here -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box2" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
       <!-- One image and text here -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box3" style="background-color:lavender;">
        <!-- One image and text here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

How to center the components horizontally in the div?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle or plnkr?

Comment: post your html markup or a fiddle would be better

Comment: `text-align: center`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give `text-align: center;` to all the three box.

```
.box1, .box2, .box3 {

    width: 33.333%;
    height: 300px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mv0g05Lf/)**

Comment: Yeah I am shifting the boxes. Just shift text works.

Answer (score 0):

To center the text, you could use

```
text-align: center;
```

To center the images, you need to put a margin on them

```
.blocks img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

give the imgs a `width: 100%` and center the text

```css
.blocks {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;
  height: 350px;
}

.box1,
.box2,
.box3 {
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 300px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box1,
.box2,
.box3 {
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 300px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
img{
  width: 100%;
}
h5{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="blocks">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box1" style="background-color:lavender;">
    <!-- One image and text here -->
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/IMiabf0.jpg" alt="" />
    <h5>This is Cute Cat</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box2" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
    <!-- One image and text here -->
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/IMiabf0.jpg" alt="" />
    <h5>This is Cute Cat</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box3" style="background-color:lavender;">
    <!-- One image and text here -->
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/IMiabf0.jpg" alt="" />
    <h5>This is Cute Cat</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic to centre align the container is fine, but there are some spacing between those components. hence, all components doesn't fit in blocks.

Adding float:left; to each box will fix the issue.

```css
.blocks {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;
  height: 350px; 
}


.box1, .box2, .box3 {

    width: 33.333%;
    height: 300px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    float: left;

}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box1" style="background-color:lavender;">
       <img src="pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:100px;height:100px;">

  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box2" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
       <img src="pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box3" style="background-color:lavender;">
       <img src="pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
  </div>
</div>
```